# How to make selection box in Canvas to select any object it touches not only objects it embraces?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, kineticjs, konvajs

There is a great tutorial [Selecting Multiple Objects with KineticJS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/685901/Selecting-Multiple-Objects-with-KineticJS) that teaches you how to create a selection box in HTML Canvas in order to select multiple objects, but the author *Michelle Higgins* wrote his code to select object that embraced by the selection box.

The following JavaScript code expresses the algorithm:

```js
var pos = rectSel.getAbsolutePosition();

//get the extents of the selection box
var selRecXStart = parseInt(pos.x);
var selRecXEnd = parseInt(pos.x) + parseInt(rectSel.attrs.width);
var selRecYStart = parseInt(pos.y);
var selRecYEnd = parseInt(pos.y) + parseInt(rectSel.attrs.height);

//get the extents of the group to compare to
var grpXStart = parseInt(grp.attrs.x);
var grpXEnd = parseInt(grp.attrs.x) + parseInt(grp.attrs.width);
var grpYStart = parseInt(grp.attrs.y);
var grpYEnd = parseInt(grp.attrs.y) + parseInt(grp.attrs.height);

//Are we inside the selction area?
if ((selRecXStart <= grpXStart && selRecXEnd >= grpXEnd) && 
    (selRecYStart <= grpYStart && selRecYEnd >= grpYEnd))
{
  if (arSelected.indexOf(grp.getName()) < 0)
  {
    arSelected.push(grp.getName());

    var tmpX = parseInt(grp.attrs.x);
    var tmpY = parseInt(grp.attrs.y);

    var rectHighlight = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: tmpX,
      y: tmpY,
      height: grp.attrs.height,
      width: grp.attrs.width,
      fill: 'transparent',
      name: 'highlightBlock',
      stroke: '#41d6f3',
      strokeWidth: 3
    });

    layer.add(rectHighlight);
  }
}
```

The question is: How to make selection box to select any object it touches not only objects it embraces?

P.S: Here is a working [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/basefubeye/edit?html,output).

Comment: I know there is Konvajs that is the new of Kineticjs

Comment: I only need the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current approach checks whether an object is completely contained in the selection rectangle. An interval `obj` is completely contained in another interval `sel` when:

```
    sel.start <= obj.start && obj.end <= sel.end
```

When you just want the objects to overlap, test:

```
    sel.start <= obj.end && obj.start <= sel.end
```

By interval, I mean a single dimension. You must, of course, test the condition for both `x` and `y`. Note the the second condition is the first one with their right-hand side swapped.

For your example, change the hit test from:

```
        //Are we inside the selction area?
        if (selRecXStart <= grpXStart
         && selRecXEnd >= grpXEnd
         && selRecYStart <= grpYStart
         && selRecYEnd >= grpYEnd)
        { ...
```

to:

```
        //Are we inside the selction area?
        if (selRecXStart <= grpXEnd
         && selRecXEnd >= grpXStart
         && selRecYStart <= grpYEnd
         && selRecYEnd >= grpYStart)
        { ...
```

Comment: The comparison was comparing the points like this || and you changed it to become like this X, well done.